# log4j - on ERROR, log DEBUG?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm relatively new to log4j (v2), but I believe I've exhausted my resources, so I come to ask my question here.

I have a working log4j configuration, which I will append to the end of my question. The application is run every x minutes using a cronjob.

The log4j behaviour I'd like to see is the following:

1. All INFO (and up) logging is done to file A
2. All ERROR (and up) logging is done to file B
3. In case of an ERROR (or up), a mail is sent containing the DEBUG (and up) lines of the given execution.

I have achieved 1 and 2 using the configuration below. Is number 3 also possible using log4j (if not, why not?) and if so, how?

The current configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RandomAccessFile name="LogFile" fileName="/var/log/fileA.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </RandomAccessFile>
    <RandomAccessFile name="ErrorLogFile" fileName="/var/log/fileB.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </RandomAccessFile>
    <SMTP name="MailError" subject="Error occurred" to="a@b.com" smtpHost="mail.foo.bar" from="b@c.net"/>
    <Async name="Async">
      <AppenderRef ref="LogFile"/>
    </Async>
    <Async name="Errors">
      <AppenderRef ref="ErrorLogFile"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="MailError"/>
    </Async>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="INFO"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="Async" level="INFO"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="Errors" level="ERROR"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Number 3 should be possible by buffering log-statements, as suggested [here](http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/Buffered-Appender-td1603.html) for logback (something similar should be available in log4j).

Comment: @vanOekel Okay but then I would have to write my own appender?

Comment: Yes, but it is a common use case (write debug-logging after detecting an error) so I expect a common solution to be available somewhere, I just can't find it.

Comment: @vanOekel I can't find it either :( And I don't know if it's possible, because it would be some kind of "inverse ThresholdFilter", but log4j only knows ACCEPT/NEUTRAL/DENY, where NEUTRAL means "see next rule, if in the end it's non-conclusive, then ACCEPT". While I need the inverse of that ("if non-conclusive, then DENY"). I doubt that's possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve this with a [ThresholdFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter). Make your root logger level TRACE so that it sends all events to all appenders, then put different threshold filters on each appender. The log4j2 manual contains an example.

---

(EDIT) After understanding the requirements better, I think the [SMTP Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) already does what you need: it internally keeps a buffer of the events (512 by default) that preceded the ERROR event that triggered the email. These preceding events will be included in the email.

Comment: Hmmm help me out here if you want.. I can imagine a ThresholdFilter for  DEBUG/INFO/WARN to be NEUTRAL and a ThresholdFilter for ERROR and up to be ACCEPT. But if I read the [log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html) correctly, this won't do it for me:

_If the value NEUTRAL is returned, then the next filter in the chain is consulted. If there are no more filters in the chain, then the log event is logged. Thus, in the presence of no filters, the default behaviour is to log all logging events._ That still results in logging if no ERROR.

Comment: I don't know when to DENY. I only know when to ACCEPT. I can't create a rule containing a DENY, except if I can create a rule "if none of the rules contains an ERROR, i want to DENY".. And I don't believe that's possible?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't fully understand your problem description. You mention "ERROR(and up)". Can you be more explicit? I assume you meant ERROR/WARN/FATAL. If you want to include trace/debug/info/error but exclude warn/fatal you could have separate DENY filters for the levels you don't want... Or perhaps I'm still not getting it. :-)

Comment: If one execution of my application yields only DEBUG and INFO messages, I don't need any output in my mail, then everything went fine. But if my application, anywhere in its run, outputs an ERROR, FATAL or SEVERE (ERROR and up), I'd like to receive ALL messages from that specific run (DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, SEVERE) in my mailbox. Because in that case, the debug info is interesting too.. Does this clarify my question a bit more?

Comment: I see. The SMTP appender keeps a small buffer (512 events by default) of all log events that preceded the ERROR event that triggered the email. So this buffer will include the TRACE, DEBUG and INFO events that preceded the triggering log event to give you context on what happened. This is already part of the SMPT Appender implementation. If this is what you are looking for, then there is no need for any custom coding or configuration.